# how to refresh jstree with html instead rebuilding it

Tags: jstree

my code builds an html and initiates the jstree with that html :

```
var html = buildHtmlunorderedList()
$("#tree").html(html);
$("#tree").jstree({
    "core":{"multiple":false},
    "state":{"key":"vmsTree22"},
            "plugins":["state","sort"]
}).bind("select_node.jstree",handleLeftClick);`
```

This work perfect.
now , every few minutes the html is built again and i want to refresh the jstree with it without the need to destroy it and initiate again (which cause a flick every time the tree is built again) :

```
inside a loop {

 html = buildHtmlunorderedList();
  var tree = $('#tree').jstree({
            "core":{"data":html}
});
tree.refresh(true);
}
```

but i am getting an error : *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined* 
(in jstree.js : `var c = this.get_container_ul()[0].className;`) 
which seams it doesn't find the first children of class jstree-children.

what i am doing wrong ?
I didn't find any straight forward example of how to refresh the entire html of the tree without destroying it and build it again.

thanks for any help

Comment: Glad it helped! Can you then accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace data as below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/1fwkas79/).

```
$("#tree").jstree().settings.core.data = newData;
$("#tree").jstree().refresh(true);
```